# Does internet explorer pass somehow "click location" when using image as input type?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

When I'm clicking on image "button" in firefox I'm getting values passed in query such as: `?x=19&y=4`, however it's not showing up in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and other "webkit" browsers (Safari...) are only going to submit the x and y data of an image element, not the element name.  This is what the upcoming html5 specifies. Internet Explorer and Opera (and, in fact, older versions of Firefox) are handling this the way that would be more intuitive, i.e. submitting the name of the image element as data.

This is most certainly a browser quirk, and if it is at all important to include or exclude this data from your query string, you should consider a different method to submit your form data.

[This](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/382/firefox-4-change-input-type-image-only-submits-x-and-y-not-name) is what I found from a quick search: